# is it pyttsx3 bug with print function?

Tags: python, debugging, printing, pyttsx

Here is a simple text to speech program. All it does is that it takes in a sentence and a speaker(not from user) and prints the word at the time it is supposed to speak that word. But the problem arises with the print function(The one marked with #*/).When this program gets executed I want to print the sentence in a single line. But when print function(#*/ marked) is argument print(" ",end="") it first speaks the content and then prints the whole line.

source code:-

```
import pyttsx;
    def onStar(name):
        print(name+":-",end="")
def onWord(name, location, length):
    for x in range(location,length+location+1) :
        print(a[x],end="")

    print()    #*/      The function I am talking about.


#case1(works correctly)                  case2(does not work correctly[bug])
#    print("")                          print("",end="")
#    print()                       
#    or just any print() without end as 2nd arg.


sentence=a='The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
speaker="narrator"
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.connect('started-utterance', onStart)
engine.connect('started-word', onWord)
engine.say(a,speaker)
engine.runAndWait()
del engine
```

output :-

case 1
The words get printed with the speech but a every word is on next line

Narrator:-
The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog.

case2:-
The text gets printed correctly but it gets printed after the sentence has been spoken.

Narrator:-The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

ps:-Its like python does not want me to print the sentence in the row.

Comment: This code cannot be run. Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve] that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `flush=True` on the print function.

```
import pyttsx3

message = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

def onWord(name, location, length):
    print(message[location:location + length], end=' ', flush=True)


engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.connect('started-word', onWord)
engine.say(message)
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: It works really fine. But interestingly running the code  from engine.connect…. to... engine.runAndWait()  n times will print the word n times in the sentence.  Example if I run the above highlighted code in this comment twice. My output will be "The The quick quick brown brown fox fox jumped jumped over over the the lazy lazy dog dog"